# Inno Setup Unicode version still doesn't display Cyrillic properly

Tags: unicode, inno-setup

I am using Inno Setup 5.5.2 (u) and all symbols are fine except the dynamically filled strings in `TStringList`. I initialize the list and add items this way:

```
Regions := TStringList.Create;
Regions.Add('Аврен');
Regions.Add('Айтос');
Regions.Add('Аксаково');
Regions.Add('Алфатар');
...
```

but them I get:

[image]

Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: You'll have to use encoded Unicode characters (in a `#$0100` format) because the Pascal Script compiler doesn't support Unicode chars as an input.

Comment: @TLama, thanks for looking into this. I can't understand something. I see in the documentation the following: "The Unicode compiler sees type 'String' as a Unicode string". Isn't this contradictory to what you are saying?

Comment: Yes, it is Unicode string, but it doesn't apply to constants in source code. In the documentation there's also stated *The new RemObjects PascalScript version used by the Unicode compiler supports Unicode,* ***but not for its input source***. *This means it does use Unicode string types as said, but* ***any literal Unicode characters in the script will be converted to ANSI***. This doesn't mean you can't display Unicode strings: you can for example instead use encoded Unicode characters to build Unicode strings (like S := #$0100 + #$0101 + 'Aa';)*.

Comment: @TLama, the problem is that based on the region value, I load cities, then names of schools in the selected city. Since I tried and I couldn't communicate with our webapp to extract the data, I had to hard code the data (and their relations) into arrays of `TStringList`s. I actually generated the script through PHP code :) Pretty crazy but I see no other solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use Unicode constants in Inno Setup at this time. In [`documentation`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=unicode) there's a quote about it (emphasized by me):

> The new RemObjects PascalScript version used by **the Unicode compiler
>   supports Unicode, but not for its input source. This means it does use
>   Unicode string types as said, but any literal Unicode characters in
>   the script will be converted to ANSI**.
>
> This doesn't mean you can't display Unicode strings: you can for
>   example instead use encoded Unicode characters to build Unicode
>   strings (like S := #$0100 + #$0101 + 'Aa';), or load the string from a
>   file using LoadStringsFromFile, or use a {cm:...} constant.

So from what is written there, you can either encode those constant chars in the following format:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  Regions: TStringList;
  ComboBox: TComboBox;
  CustomPage: TWizardPage;
begin
  CustomPage := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, 'Caption', 'Description');
  ComboBox := TComboBox.Create(WizardForm);
  ComboBox.Parent := CustomPage.Surface;

  Regions := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Regions.Add(#$0410 + #$0432 + #$0440 + #$0435 + #$043D
    Regions.Add(#$0410 + #$0439 + #$0442 + #$043E + #$0441
    Regions.Add(#$0410 + #$043A + #$0441 + #$0430 + #$043A + #$043E + #$0432 + #$043E
    Regions.Add(#$0410 + #$043B + #$0444 + #$0430 + #$0442 + #$0430 + #$0440
    ComboBox.Items.AddStrings(Regions);
  finally
    Regions.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Or you can load a list of regions by the suggested [`LoadStringsFromFile`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_loadstringsfromfile) function from an external file and with the output array fill the string list (or directly the combo box).

Or you can make an external [`custom messages`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=custommessagessection) file.

Comment: This answers my question. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome! Anyway, if I were you, I would store those values as an item per line (in Unicode) and load them by the `LoadStringsFromFile` function.

Comment: In a flat file it would be difficult (maybe even impossible) to create the relations between regions, cities and schools. Anyway I will give it a second thought. Thank you again.

Comment: In a flat file you can still make a `name=value` pairs, which you can parse when you load the file.

Comment: Note that for a bit more compactness, the `+` operator (and whitespace) between `#$xxxx` characters is optional.