# How to pass international text from Qt .pro/pri file to ISS script

Tags: qt, internationalization, inno-setup, qmake

I am using QtCreator and Inno setup to create an international installer that supports English, Japanese and a host of other languages

The approach taken before I came onto the project is to create the Inno setup script dynamically during the build using build variables and the echo command, ie:

In the Qt .PRI file

```
system(echo <some ISS command here> >> myfile)
```

This works fine for standard text eg

```
system(echo if IsWin64 then >> $$ISS)
system(echo begin >> $$ISS)
system(echo HKey := \'Wow6432Node\'; >> $$ISS)
system(echo end >> $$ISS)
```

creates in the ISS file

```
if IsWin64 then
begin
HKey := 'Wow6432Node';
end
```

However we now also want to write some foreign language text to the script file for warning messages, eg

```
system(echo alreadyInstalledMessage := \'La version XYZ est déjà installée.\'; >> $$ISS)
```

This should appear in the .ISS file as

```
alreadyInstalledMessage := 'La version XYZ est déjà installée.';
```

But its appearing as

```
alreadyInstalledMessage := 'La version XYZ est d‚j… install‚e.';
```

I'm guessing this is down to character encoding but cannot find anything on either the echo command or QMake to get it to do what I want.

Anybody know what the magic rune is to get the text to pass from the .PRI file to the .ISS file maintaining all characters. Or is there a better way?

Comment: Are you using Unicode version of Inno Setup ? If so (which you must), then try to generate your output script in UTF-8 encoding. That's the only [`documented`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_unicode.htm) Unicode format of *.iss files. And, although UTF-8 encoding is supported for *.iss script files and you can specify e.g. custom messages in your script as Unicode, you can't define constant for `[Code]` section (like e.g. in [`this example`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18309711/960757)). However, I can't help you how to produce UTF-8 output from QtCreator.

Comment: I'm not sure what the script is doing with it, but be aware that hard-coding `Wow6432Node` into anything is usually the wrong thing to do.  Inno will by default target the 32-bit registry anyway, and there are other (better) means to tell it to do otherwise.

Comment: @TLama. Thanks for the heads up on the unicode version - I have downloaded it in any case. As you say, the problem isnt InnoSetup, its getting QtCreator to output UTF8 characters to the ISS file.

Comment: @Miral. Good spot - I'll address that when I get it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot achieve this with Qt 4 qmake unfortunately.

However, you could use the 'log' qmake function with Qt 5 which would serve the purpose you need. This is just for your convenience as qmake cannot do what you are trying to achieve here.

It is also feature frozen, so it is most likely not getting any useful feature backported.

You will need to reiterate your project, and solve this in a different manner.